# Piping (multiple) expressions in RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set that varies greatly in general, but I managed to find some similarities. The data may be completely different but they do have same ending classes. I am wondering if it is feasible to use multiple regex expressions with each other (pipe them together with |).

Something like this:

```
"^([A-Z0-9]+|[d-k0-5]+|[xyz7-9]+)\\s+(Flag1|FLAG1)$";
```

Would this be a valid design and will that work? Or do I have to make multiple regex strings and run them every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way. This will match strings like:

```
TEST009 Flag1
def345 FLAG1
zxy789     Flag1
```

Without any issue.